# Hide Load More Records Button ASP.net MVC Ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load more records on click via ajax, in my asp.net mvc5 web application. But I am new to javascript and I can't figure out how to hide load more button when current page is equal to total pages.

**javascript code:**

```
function LoadMoreUR(total_pages) {
    loadRecords(total_pages);
}
var page = 0;
var _inCallback = false;
function loadRecords(total_pages) {
    if (page > -1 && !_inCallback) {
        _inCallback = true;
        page++;
        $('div#loading').html('<p><img src="/Content/loading.gif"></p>');
        $.get("/UserReviews/@ViewData["DeviceID"]/" + page, function (data) {
            if (data != '') {
                $("#UserReviewsList").append(data);
            }
            else {
                page = -1;
            }

            _inCallback = false;
            $('div#loading').empty();
        });
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
    <div id="UserReviewsList">
        @Html.Partial("_user_reviews")
    </div>
    <div id="loadingbtn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="LoadMUR" onclick="LoadMoreUR(@ViewData["TotalPages"])" >Load More</button>
        <div id="loading"></div>
    </div>
```

If there are 3 records for a device, and I am loading one record on each click. 
I want to hide `loadingbtn` div when `page` is equal to `total_pages`.

Please help me figure this out. Thanks

**My Solution** (please tell me if I am doing something wrong)

```
function LoadMoreUR(totalpages) {
    loadProducts(totalpages);
}
var page = 0;
var _inCallback = false;
function loadProducts(totalpages) {
    if((page + 2) == totalpages && !_inCallback)
    {
        $('div#loading1').empty();
    }
    if (page > -1 && !_inCallback) {
        _inCallback = true;
        page++;
        $('div#loading').html('<p><img src="/Content/loading.gif"></p>');
        $.get("/UserReviews/Index/@ViewData["DeviceID"]/" + page, function (data) {
            if (data != '') {
                $("#UserReviewsList").append(data);
            }
            else {
                page = -1;
            }

            _inCallback = false;
            $('div#loading').empty();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ajax response you have to get whole records count and Compare with displayed records. If you are binding in table you can get count of rows.

```
var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
```

In ajax response return the number of records each time to check condition to hide the button.

```
If(rowCount == TotalRecordCount )
{
 $("#loadingbtn").hide()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it and Updated my question with answer.